GitHub command after local text changes
On my GitHub, I have forked https://github.com/fvwmorg/fvwmorg.github.io
I made one Pull Request a few days ago from
https://github.com/rasatpc/fvwmorg.github.io/tree/pr-whyfvwm

fvwmorg.github.io asked me to make a few corrections to the requested text.
On my local machine (/home/amurt/GitHub/fvwmorg.github.io) the file is now corrected.

What are the terminal commands to update my pr-whyfvwm branch and send the new change to fvwmorg.github.io?

Push the changes?

Push it without creating an additional commit. Currently, there is 1 commits. Normal push makes it 2 commits.

So rewrite your commit, then force-push.

Read my modification on the question.

I want the exact terminal commands.

It's unclear what if anything your actual problem is. Yes, you'd have two commits, that's not a problem, or if it is you can rewrite it (research rewriting commits, and force pushing - SO isn't here to type everything for you). Learn more about the workflow here: https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests.


What are the terminal commands to update my pr-whyfvwm branch and send the new change to fvwmorg.github.io?

Once you open a pull-request, until either pull-request is closed or merged, new commits on your branch will appear on your pull request too.
What it means is that you should just push your commits to your pr-whyfvwm branch, your changes/new commits will be reflected on your pull request to fvwmorg.github.io repository.

I want the exact terminal commands.


If you are not on pr-whyfvwm branch, switch to it using git switch pr-whyfvwm command.
add your changes: git add . or git add specific-files
commit your changes: git commit -m 'commit-message'
push your commits to your repository: git push origin pr-whyfvwm


Update based on OP's clarification of what they want

I was asked to amend/squeeze to one commit. How to do, terminal commands?

What you need is Interactive rebase and git force-push
Commands:

git rebase -i HEAD~n (n is the number of commits you want to amend)


Running git rebase with the -i flag begins an interactive rebasing session.

It opens up following file on your text-editor:
pick 2231360 some old commit
pick ee2adc2 Adds new feature


# Rebase 2cf755d..ee2adc2 onto 2cf755d (9 commands)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick = use commit
# r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# d, drop = remove commit


On the commit lines that you want "amend/sqeeze",  You should replace pick with either s or f

Save and close the file

push your changes to remote repository:


git push origin pr-whyfvwm --force

Here is the beginner friendly resource to learn more about interactive rebase

When I started a month ago, after each change, I pushed it with GitHub Desktop (GUI). It accumulated many commits.

4Btm Decor … 1f2c680
4Btm Decor … 22068b9
4Btm decor … bb7a6e6
4Btm Decor … c4ca57f
4Btm Decor … 3f98585
I was asked to amend/squeeze to one commit.
How to do, terminal commands?

I will do one more test with a new pull request, not to miss any.

After testing, a summary with a few minor points: 1) git switch pr-whyfvwm 2) git add  3) git commit -m "commit-message" 4) git push origin pr-whyfvwm --force

AFTER 2nd edit: 1) git rebase -i HEAD~2  and 2) Replace bottom pick with squash.

@RasatPC  If answer solved your problem, please accept and upvote it so it can help others too.

"To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer". I don't see any "check marks".

@RasatPC it is  below the vote down button, in gray color, on the left side of the answer
